# Youtube Player Mouse Over Event

Tags: flash, youtube, mouse, youtube-api, watermark

a client of mine wants this effect at his youtube videos.
I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything...

Does someone know if this is made using the youtube API somehow or its just a flash player that loads the youtube player within it using a mask ?

Reference: http://pensenovotv.com.br/descricao/o-povo-canta-o-jingle-de-haddad?source=destaquegrandesuperior

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they are loading the video and then mask and control it using their own flash code. It's pretty simple to load youtube into your flash, see f.ex. here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3youtube/

Also, you could just pass the link to the video to your swf via FlashVars.